# Python: Nested list with similar values to dictionnary

Tags: python

Consider this nested list:

```
nested_list = [['GroupA',10],['GroupA',20],['GroupB',30],['GroupC',30]]
```

What is the best solution to get this expected output:

```
{
'GroupA':[10,20],
'GroupB':[30],
'GroupC':[30],
}
```

Note that this is a minimal example. Basically, I'm looking for a way to group similar values at `[0]` position in a list of list into a dictionnary.

I tried a solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16359052/7692463):

```
mapping_dict = { k[0]: k[1:] for k in nested_list }
```

But this is overriding the first value `10` which is incorrect. I did not found any other answer that was for the wanted output.

Comment: you cannot do that with a comprehension because there's an accumulation effect. that's a classic, the duplicate fully answers your question.

Comment: _there's an accumulation effect_, what does that mean ?

Comment: maybe I meant "cumulative effect". it means that first time it creates the key/value for groupA, and the second time, it reuses the value to store the new integer. That cannot be done with a list comprehension. Well, you can, using `sort` and `itertools.groupby` but that's less efficient than a good old `defaultdict(list)` like the link demonstrates.

Comment: you're welcome. I try to explain _why_ I'm closing questions so askers don't get frustrated.

Comment: Well reinventing the wheel is against any decent programmers interest. So I'm far from frustated.

Comment: some people take it the wrong way and think their problem is unique (adding one more answer would just add pollution to the site)... anyway, the best way is the defaultdict, and too bad for the beloved one-liners: it's just not the best way here. Good luck.